# How to create a shapefile having Voronoi diagrams from the shapefile of an existing region?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, voronoi-thiessen, scipy.spatial

I have a shapefile of a region and I want to generate random sub regions of that shapefile using Voronoi class of scipy.spatial package of Python. But I am a newbie to GIS. I found out about Voronoi from StackOverflow comments. I don't know how to do that for a city with contoured boundaries.

Any suggestions, code snippets or suggestions will be a great help to me.

Comment: You should mention which posts you looked at from StackOverflow to stop others mentioning the same ones like this one probably: [From Voronoi tessellation to Shapely polygons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27548363/from-voronoi-tessellation-to-shapely-polygons)

Comment: voronoi polygons are generated from a set of **points**, not regions. What are you trying to do here? Use the centroids of some regions? Its also tricky because voronoi polygons on the outside can be unbounded, ie go off to infinity, which makes it hard for a GIS to process...

Comment: @Spacedman I am trying to divide a given city map into random sub-regions. I generated random points to act as centroids inside the given city map. I am clueless how to proceed forward.

Comment: @Joseph I had not seen the link you have mentioned. Thanks. Let me check it.